# Python not reading file, returning empty result

Tags: python, python-2.7

aaa.txt:

```
aszczx
d
as
w
ad
```

python script:

```
f = open('aaa.txt','r')
f.read()
f.close()
```

Console:

```
C:\Python27>test.py

C:\Python27>
```

Why is it not displaying the contents of the file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not displaying the contents of the file, just reading it.

For instance you could do something like this:

```
with open('aaa.txt') as infp:
    data = infp.read()

print data # display data read
```

Using `with` will also close the file for your automatically

Comment: ah great, not sure how I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the asker used `read()` while you used `readlines()` - the two *are* different. `readlines()` will return a list of strings, while `read()` will return a big string.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the lines you read in to a variable, then print it later.

```
lines = f.read()
# Later...
print lines
```