# Python, cannot open a text file

Tags: python, text

I have a text file named android.txt (with a couple of thousand of lines) which I try to open with python, my code is:

```
f = open('/home/user/android.txt', 'r')
```

But when I'm doing:

```
f.read()
```

the result is:

```
''
```

I chmod 777 /home/user/android.txt but the result remains the same

Comment: Try using `f.readlines()`

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571399/python-not-reading-file-returning-empty-result)

Comment: show the [*complete* (but minimal) code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you reading from the file more than once  before printing it? (e.g., `f.read(); print(repr(f.read()))` -- don't do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result would be empty string not empty list and it's because your file size is larger than [your memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739913/what-is-the-max-length-of-a-python-string)(based on your python version and your machine)! So python doesn't assigned the file content to a variable!

For getting rid of this problem you need to process your file line by line.

```
with open('/home/user/android.txt') as f :
    for line in f:
         #do stuff with line
```

Comment: there is not such thing as *"python string object capacity"*. You might get `MemoryError` but you won't get an empty string just because a file is too large to fit in memory.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Indeed.I just wanted to make it understandable for OP. Actually it's the memory and can be used for any object!

Answer (score 3):

You are not displaying the contents of the file, just reading it.

For instance you could do something like this:

```
with open('/home/user/android.txt') as infp:
    data = infp.read()

print data # display data read
```

Using with will also close the file for your automatically

Comment: I just tried but print data returns an empty string

Comment: Then you should refer to Kasra's solution for the next part of the problem

Answer (score 0):

try making a variable that contains `f:read()` and printing it

```
f = open('/home/user/android.txt', 'r')
rf = f:read()
print(rf)
```

else try making `print(repr(f:read()))`